# ReflectionException: Class \MenuBlockKernelViewSubscriber does not exist

Tags: deployment

Doing a simple staging to production migration, copied all files, and the database,. Imported the database successfully but now when visiting homepage of the site I get the below error message/messages:

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

```
**ReflectionException: Class Drupal\menu_block\EventSubscriber\MenuBlockKernelViewSubscriber does not exist in ReflectionClass->__construct() (line 30 of /var/www/vhosts/cpp.org/httpdocs/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/Compiler/RegisterEventSubscribersPass.php).**
ReflectionClass->__construct('Drupal\menu_block\EventSubscriber\MenuBlockKernelViewSubscriber') (Line: 30)
Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Compiler\RegisterEventSubscribersPass->process(Object) (Line: 141)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile(Object) (Line: 788)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile() (Line: 1322)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->compileContainer() (Line: 896)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer() (Line: 472)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot() (Line: 668)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Comment: Do you mean a deployment rather than a migration? Drupal 8 sites are now not as simple as copying files if you haven't run composer. Perhaps the composer autoloader is confused and needs to be dumped?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, typically in the past, it was pretty basic, copy files, export/import database, and modify settings.php with the proper database/details. 

I will check into the composer autoloader, thanks for the tip mradcliffe.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that's the issue, but it could be. If you have drush installed as part of your site, then maybe a `./vendor/bin/drush cr` could help as well.

Comment: Thanks, i am talking with our team as they are finding out that our drush version does not support drupal 8.